# Atmospheric correction for Sentinel-2 imagery in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth, sentinel2

I want to apply atmospheric correction on Sentinel-2 imagery in Google Earth Engine(GEE). I saw the Sammurphy code which is written in Python and unfortunately it did not work for me. I tried the dark pixel subtraction method using the code(Java)  below but it results in a total dark image over my region of interest.

I am new to both Earth Engine and JavaScript. Has anyone tried using the dark pixel subtraction or any other atmospheric correction on Sentinel 2 imagery in GEE (preferably a code written in Java)?

```js
var toa=maskedComposite1;
var thresh= 0.5;

var dark=findDarkPixels(toa, thresh)
print(dark);


//Function to find dark pixels from threshold on sum of NIR, SWIR1, & SWIR2 bands
//Returns classified image with binary [0,1] 'dark' band
// toa: Sentinel 2 image converted to surface radiance
// thresh: threshold (0.2 - 0.5) value for sum of NIR, SWIR1 & SWIR2 bands
function findDarkPixels(toa, thresh) {
  var darkPixels1 = toa.select(['B8','B11','B12']);
  var darkPixels = darkPixels1.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).lt(thresh);
  var filtered = darkPixels.focal_mode(0.1, 'square', 'pixels');
  Map.addLayer(filtered,{},'darkPixel');
  return filtered.rename(['dark']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need specific atmospheric correction then you can use the Level-2A Sentinel-2 data already available in GEE. [Here is the link to dataset info.](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR) The atmospheric correction for this data set is performed by sen2cor. Note the time period the data are available for as Level-2A data is not available for the entire data archive.

Comment: Thanks Agris for your comment. Currently, I am trying to implement atmospheric correction on S2 imagery(using Level 1C -TOA) of varying spatial and temporal scales. So, I assume it is best to apply the atmospheric correction myself instead of using the surface reflectance (Level 2A- BOA) directly due to image unavailability at interested regions and time periods as you pointed out.